# How to make executable version of software in Android?

Tags: android, executable

I am almost done with my project in android, now I want to make the executable version of the application.

I need to demonstrate it in .exe form as soft app as on emulator, not by built and debug process from eclipse.

Comment: Try [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) from the Android developer documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make .EXE for demonstration of a Android Software built in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862067/how-to-make-exe-for-demonstration-of-a-android-software-built-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bin folder and look for your

```
[appname].apk
```

file. Eclipse should build one as it builds your project. Then you can take this apk and move it to your device and install it! (Using a file explorer like ASTRO and enabling non-market apps to be installed).

Comment: I need to demonstrate it in .exe form as soft app as on emulator, not by built and debug process from eclipse.

Comment: i don't want to move it to device, i want to make EXE for demonstration