# How to make .EXE for demonstration of a Android Software built in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, exe

I am almost done with my project in android, now I want to make the executable version of the application.

I need to demonstrate it in .exe form as soft app as on emulator, not by built and debug process from eclipse.

need immediate idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make executable version of software in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845655/how-to-make-executable-version-of-software-in-android)

Comment: You've now asked the same question three times. Please don't do this. If you have something to add please edit your existing question and comment on answers you've already received.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some legwork:

1. Create the .apk bundle
2. Create an Android virtual device
3. Boot your emulator
4. Install your .apk into the emulator.
5. Create a batch file to launch the emulator with the correct AVD, place the zip file somewhere prominent
6. Zip up the whole works, and distribute that.