# How to create a batch file to launch the emulator with the AVD in android?

Tags: batch-file, android-emulator

In reference to my previous question regarding making the .EXE file for demonstration

[How to make .EXE for demonstration of a Android Software built in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862067/how-to-make-exe-for-demonstration-of-a-android-software-built-in-eclipse)

Can anyone explain creating batch file to launch the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code and save it as a batch file. All you need to do is swap out the "AVD_for_Nexus_6_by_Google" with one of your own emulators.

`cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools" && .\emulator -avd AVD_for_Nexus_6_by_Google`

If you want to see a list of all your installed emulators save and run the following in a batch file. The pause at the end is to make sure the window doesn't close when the command is complete.

`cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools" && .\emulator -list-avds
pause`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command to launch the emulator

```
emulator -avd <avdname>
```

this assumes the path to emulator is set on your system

Comment: TO be honest I don't know the commands, I just tried to make the EXE and batch file but it donesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For run test from command prompt you can use @zair-naim answer

if you find error `PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, just add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to your Environment Variables

[image: add Android sdk root to environment variables]

Open new Command Prompt and run again

1. Create batch File "run_avd.bat" on Desktop or another place
2. Edit and Add this line of code

`cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools"
start emulator -avd Nexus5x` change Nexus5x with your avd name

3. Save file and run batch file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and save it as a batch file.

```
cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator && emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_28
```

Answer (score 0):

create batch file for example Pixel2.bat

and enter following commands:

```
set PATH="D:\Android\Sdk\emulator"  
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28
```

save the file.
you can directly run emulator without opening android studio.

Answer (score 0):

create batch file for example pixeldevice.bat

- open notepad
- put the following command

> @Echo off
>
> @Echo %cd%
>
> C:
>
> CD "C:\Users<may different>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator"
>
> @Echo %cd%
>
> emulator -avd pixel2Emulator
>
> Pause

1. CD "C:\Users<may different>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator"  -
   navigate to emulator path
2. @Echo %cd% -- display current path
3. emulator -avd pixel2Emulator - run emulator