# How to make an EXE file using .apk file

Tags: android, adb, apk

am almost done with my project in android, now I want to make the executable version of the application.

I need to demonstrate it in .exe form as soft app as on emulator, not by built and debug process from eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make executable version of software in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845655/how-to-make-executable-version-of-software-in-android)

Comment: You've now asked the same question three times.  Please don't do this.  If you have something to add please edit your existing question and comment on answers you've already received.

Comment: but no body bother to answer back, then what should I do?

Comment: OK... I added some more useful explanation.

Comment: You don't need to run the debugger to demo your app in the emulator. Just launch the same emulator you've been using to debug with emulator -avd <avd_name>, not sure running that command plus a couple of clicks to open your app once the emulator is up are worth the extra effort to create an exe or batch

Answer (score 2):

what the op is asking for is simple - he wants to create a MS Windows program file that runs just like the APK he's made.

Unfortunately this cannot be done.  The only way to 'show off' your program is as people have stated:

1. Through the emulator on Windows
2. On an acual device (Once installed, you can disconnect the device from the computer and use it like a normal app)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an APK file into a .exe file. APK files hold Android apps as self-installable files already - opening an APK file on a phone or the emulator will start the installation process. It sounds like you just want to sign the app with a 'proper' key rather than using a debug key. To do that, read the [official page on signing apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Actually, I wan to make an EXE file of the project for the demonstration of the project to get rid of the process of debugging everytime and running code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a .EXE file for doing what you want. You can just create a bat file that executes `adb` commands that will: install and start your application in the emulator. I guess, the problem here is that you don't understand how the APK files work... I'm just saying.

OK... in order to install an Android application using `adb` (which is basically what Eclipse does in the background) you need to do this:

```
adb install path/name_app.apk
```

Then, you can start the application by using `adb shell am` command. You can find info here: http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/instrumentation_testing.html

Another thing you have to take in account is that you will have to run the AVD before installing and executing your application: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html

All those commands you have to execute (may be using a .bat file as I mentioned before) are executables that you can find in the android-sdk\tools directory.

Comment: Can you please code the adb command to "adb commands that will: install and start your application in the emulator" as you specified in your answer

Answer (score 1):

When I have a client that want's to show an app, at conference for example, I always use Bluestacks it's not perfect but it allows you to run android apps on your computer without doing all the technical stuff (like installing an emulator etc).

To install an app on your you computer using the Bluestacks device/emulator you simply click on the apk.

http://bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a project/application in `Eclipse` then along with this you also have created the `.apk` file. Android can run `.apk` files, so go to the place where your project have been saved and open it, like this `Open Project -->bin-->.apk`.

Now send the `.apk` file to your android phone through Bluetooth or copy it.